# Total depth of a binary search tree in python

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the total depth of a BST in python(such that the root is at depth 1, its children depth 2, those children depth 3 etc) and the total is all of those depths added together. Ive been trying for about 5 hours straight now and cannot figure it out. Here is the code I have produced so far

```
class BinaryTreeVertex:
    '''vertex controls for the BST'''

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.right = None 
        self.left = None
        self.value = value

    ...

    def total_Depth(self):
        print ("val:", self.value)
        if self.left and self.right:
            return (self.left.total_Depth()) + 1 and (self.right.total_Depth()) + 1
        elif self.left:
            return 1 + self.left.total_Depth()
        elif self.right:
            return 1 + self.right.total_Depth()
        else:
            return 1
...

tree = BinarySearchTree()     
arr = [6,10,20,8,3]
for i in arr:
    tree.insert(i)
tree.searchPath(20)
print (tree.total_Depth()) #this calls the total_depth from vertex class
```

The generated tree then looks like this.

```
   6         # Depth 1
___|___
3     10     # Depth 2
    ___|__
    8    20  # Depth 3
```

But when I run it it prints:

```
val: 6
val: 3
val: 10
val: 8
val: 20
3
```

The 3 should actually be an 11 with this tree but I cannot figure out how to get it. Please help

edit: To clarify, i am NOT looking for the max depth, I know how to find this. I need the total depth the way i explained, where the depth is the level of the tree. it would be 11 here as 6 would have depth 1, 3 and 10 depth 2, and 8 and 20 depth 3, where 1+2+2+3+3=11. I need it for a ratio regarding run times

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish doing `return (self.left.total_Depth()) + 1 and (self.right.total_Depth()) + 1`? This is always going to return the depth of the right branch plus one. You probably want `max((self.left.total_Depth()) + 1, (self.right.total_Depth()) + 1)`

Comment: How did you figure out your desired return value is 11? I think you are confusing tree values and tree depth, which are completely separate things. Do you want the depth of the tree or a sum of the values traversed along a path?

Comment: https://github.com/joowani/binarytree

Comment: I very much doubt you want to **sum** the depths at each levels (and in any case that total would just be D(D+1)/2 ). Presumably you only want to find max depth.

Comment: In any case your bug is `expr1 and expr2`. Olivier's answer shows the clean way of implementing your depth function in three lines.

Comment: Also, Python PEP-8 standard does not mix cases, so `total_Depth` should be `total_depth`; really it should just be `depth`. CamelCase is reserved for class names only, never functions, variables, methods, properties.

Comment: HI, i am looking for total depth NOT max depth. the max depth is rather simple to find

Comment: What do you need total depth for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem comes from this line.

```
return (self.left.total_Depth()) + 1 and (self.right.total_Depth()) + 1
```

Using `and` will return the leftmost falsy value provided, or rightmost if they are all truthy. In that case, it actually ends up always returning `self.right.total_Depth() + 1`.

What I recommend is keeping track of the nodes depth through a keyword argument, I called it `_depth` to emphasize that it should be private, i.e. not provided by the user.

```
class BinaryTreeVertex:

    ...

    def total_depth(self, _depth=1):

        if self.left and self.right:
            return self.left.total_depth(_depth=_depth + 1) \
                   + self.right.total_depth(_depth=_depth + 1) \
                   + _depth

        elif self.left:
            return _depth + self.left.total_depth(_depth=_depth + 1)

        elif self.right:
            return _depth + self.right.total_depth(_depth=_depth + 1)

        else:
            return _depth
```

You can also shorten this like so.

```
def total_depth(self, _depth=1):

    left_depth  = self.left.total_depth(_depth=_depth + 1)  if self.left else 0
    right_depth = self.right.total_depth(_depth=_depth + 1) if self.right else 0

    return left_depth + right_depth + _depth
```

In both case you can then get the total depth like this.

```
tree.total_depth()
```

Comment: hi, unfortunately i am aware of how to get max depth. I am indeed looking for total depth. I need both for a run time assignment

Comment: thank you! i had an idea to use an argument but couldn't figure it out!